# django templates are not rendering

Tags: python, django, templates

I am new to django. I am not able to render a template using two or multi level dictionary.Below are my view and template code.

code from view.py

```
myList = {
    'ParentABC': {
        'ABC' : '#'
        }
    }
return render_to_response('index.html', myList)
```

I have tried with two different templates but no luck:
Template1-

```
<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
        {% for eachCategory in myList %}
        <li class="bold"><a class="collapsible-header  waves-effect waves-teal">{{ eachCategory }}</a>
              <div class="collapsible-body" style="">
                <ul>
                {% for subCat in myList.eachCategory %}
                  <li><a href="#">{{ subCat  }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

template 2-

```
<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
    {% for category,value  in myList.items %}
    <li class="bold"><a class="collapsible-header  waves-effect waves-teal">{{ category }}</a>
          <div class="collapsible-body" style="">
            <ul>
            {% for subcategory,value1 in value.items %}
              <li><a href="#">{{ subcategory }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

after rendering i am always getting below html:

```
<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">

        </ul>
```

Please help me for the same.

Comment: please post your settings.py for the media

Comment: it is defualt settings.py. I have only added below lines to settings.py to server static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS =  [
   BASE_DIR +'/myproject/static/' 
   ]
I am not sure how setting.py will affect my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code sample

```
 myList = {
        'myList' : {
    'ParentABC1': {
    'ABC' : '#',
    'DEF' : '#'
    },
    'ParentABC2': {
    'ABC' : '#',
    'DEF' : '#'
    },
        }

    }

<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
        {% for eachCategory, value in myList.items %}
        <li class="bold"><a class="collapsible-header  waves-effect waves-teal">{{ eachCategory }}</a>
              <div class="collapsible-body" style="">
                <ul>
                {% for subCat in value %}
                  <li><a href="#">{{ subCat  }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
              </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `{% for key, value in object.iteritems %}` if you want to iterate on an object with keys and values, or just `{% for value in object.items %}`

Something like

```
<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
    {% for eachCategory, catValue in myList.iteritems %}
    <li class="bold"><a class="collapsible-header  waves-effect waves-teal">{{ eachCategory }}</a>
          <div class="collapsible-body" style="">
            <ul>
            {% for subCat in catValue.items %}
              <li><a href="#">{{ subCat  }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Django templates don't support arguments so the use of `()` will cause the template render to fail.

Comment: @all - sorry.. I have provide both the templates same in my question. I am already using almost same template you provided. Are you able to get some mistake there.